# Side by side div with box width by percent and another by fixed width

Tags: css, responsive-design

i try to create search box for responsive layout, for search button the width is fixed 52px, but for input the width should be 100%.

```
<div class="btn_box">Search</div>
<div class="search_box">
   <input type="text" value="Search"> 
</div>

.search_box {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.btn_box {
  background-color: #5D85D0;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  float: right;
  padding: 3px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  width: 52px;
}
input {
    width:88%;
    padding:5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

now when i resize the input box will go down. You can check here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruslyrossi/34yF3/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.search_box {
   border: 1px solid #000000;
}
.btn_box {
   background-color: #5D85D0;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   float: right;
   position: relative;
   text-align: center;
   width: 52px;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
}
input {
   width: -moz-calc(100% - 52px);
   width: -webkit-calc(100% - 52px);
   width: -o-calc(100% - 52px);
   width: calc(100% - 52px);
   border: none;
   outline: none;
}

<div class="btn_box">Search</div>
<div class="search_box">
   <input type="text" value="Search">
</div>
```

Using css3 calc

Keep in mind that css3 calc is not supported in the lower versions of Internet Explorer. If you want to support it crosbrowser including ie8 & ie7 you could use jQuery.